# _TypeError (type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'String') when not acutally 'Null'

Tags: flutter, dart, model, dart-null-safety

I am having an issue where as the title describes and the screenshot shows that one of my strings in my model is being considered 'Null', when it actually isn't.

First screenshot:

[image]

As shown in my second screenshot,

[image]

I am printing the response from the API and the value in the key/value pair is actually filled. Either way, how would I deal with it if it actually were null? I need to assume at some point it could be.

I am not even trying to use this k/p anywhere in my program yet. The data is being grabbed from the api and applied to my model. I think that is where my issue lies. I think the data isn't returned fast enough and so the code determines the value as null, when it clearly isn't.

Here is my model file:

```
    import 'dart:convert';

Device deviceFromJson(String str) => Device.fromJson(json.decode(str));

class Device {
    Device({
        required this.mode,
        required this.device,
    });

    String mode;
    DeviceClass device;

    factory Device.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Device(
        mode: json["mode"],
        device: DeviceClass.fromJson(json["device"]),
    );
}

class DeviceClass {
    DeviceClass({
        required this.deviceId,
        required this.publicId,
        required this.companyId,
        required this.company,
        required this.label,
        required this.mobileProviderId,
        required this.mobileProvider,
        required this.hologramDeviceId,
        required this.hologramLinkId,
        required this.firmwareVersionId,
        required this.version,
        required this.formattedVersion,
        required this.deviceTypeId,
        required this.deviceType,
        required this.ipAddress,
        required this.recordInterval,
        required this.uploadInterval,
        required this.powerMode,
        required this.connectivity,
        required this.connectivityClass,
        required this.usersLastRecordDate,
        required this.gmtLastRecordDate,
        required this.battery,
        required this.batteryPercentage,
        required this.batteryClass,
        required this.batteryIcon,
        required this.signalQuality,
        required this.signalQualityClass,
        required this.signalQualityText,
        required this.signalQualityIcon,
        required this.queuedRecords,
        required this.command,
        required this.status,
        required this.statusClass,
        required this.purchaseDate,
        required this.warrantyPeriod,
        required this.warrantyExpires,
        required this.warrantyStatus,
        required this.temperatureClass,
        required this.temperatureMetric,
        required this.temperatureImperial,
        required this.surgeProtection,
        required this.totalProducts,
        this.temperatureLowThreshold,
        this.temperatureHighThreshold,
        this.notes,
        this.importId,
        required this.deleted,
        required this.createdBy,
        required this.lastUpdatedBy,
        required this.deletedBy,
        required this.dateCreated,
        required this.dateModified,
        required this.dateDeleted,
        required this.scope,
        required this.owner,
        required this.links,
        required this.ports,
        required this.iotDeviceTags,
        required this.entityAddresses,
        required this.availablePorts,
        required this.mobile,
    });

    String? deviceId;
    String? publicId;
    String? companyId;
    String? company;
    String label;
    String? mobileProviderId;
    String? mobileProvider;
    String? hologramDeviceId;
    String? hologramLinkId;
    String? firmwareVersionId;
    String? version;
    String? formattedVersion;
    String? deviceTypeId;
    String? deviceType;
    String? ipAddress;
    String? recordInterval;
    String? uploadInterval;
    String? powerMode;
    String? connectivity;
    String? connectivityClass;
    String? usersLastRecordDate;
    DateTime gmtLastRecordDate;
    String? battery;
    String? batteryPercentage;
    String? batteryClass;
    String? batteryIcon;
    String? signalQuality;
    String? signalQualityClass;
    String? signalQualityText;
    String? signalQualityIcon;
    String? queuedRecords;
    String? command;
    String? status;
    String? statusClass;
    DateTime? purchaseDate;
    String? warrantyPeriod;
    DateTime? warrantyExpires;
    String? warrantyStatus;
    String? temperatureClass;
    String? temperatureMetric;
    String? temperatureImperial;
    String? surgeProtection;
    String? totalProducts;
    dynamic temperatureLowThreshold;
    dynamic temperatureHighThreshold;
    dynamic notes;
    dynamic importId;
    String? deleted;
    String? createdBy;
    String? lastUpdatedBy;
    dynamic deletedBy;
    dynamic dateCreated;
    String? dateModified;
    dynamic dateDeleted;
    String? scope;
    String? owner;
    DeviceLinks links;
    List<Port> ports;
    List<IotDeviceTag> iotDeviceTags;
    List<EntityAddress> entityAddresses;
    List<String> availablePorts;
    Mobile mobile;

    factory DeviceClass.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => DeviceClass(
        deviceId: json["device_id"],
        publicId: json["public_id"],
        companyId: json["company_id"],
        company: json["company"],
        label: json["label"] ?? 'null',
        mobileProviderId: json["mobile_provider_id"],
        mobileProvider: json["mobile_provider"],
        hologramDeviceId: json["hologram_device_id"],
        hologramLinkId: json["hologram_link_id"],
        firmwareVersionId: json["firmware_version_id"],
        version: json["version"],
        formattedVersion: json["formatted_version"],
        deviceTypeId: json["device_type_id"],
        deviceType: json["device_type"],
        ipAddress: json["ip_address"],
        recordInterval: json["record_interval"],
        uploadInterval: json["upload_interval"],
        powerMode: json["power_mode"],
        connectivity: json["connectivity"],
        connectivityClass: json["connectivity_class"],
        usersLastRecordDate: json["users_last_record_date"],
        gmtLastRecordDate: DateTime.parse(json["gmt_last_record_date"]),
        battery: json["battery"],
        batteryPercentage: json["battery_percentage"],
        batteryClass: json["battery_class"],
        batteryIcon: json["battery_icon"],
        signalQuality: json["signal_quality"],
        signalQualityClass: json["signal_quality_class"],
        signalQualityText: json["signal_quality_text"],
        signalQualityIcon: json["signal_quality_icon"],
        queuedRecords: json["queued_records"],
        command: json["command"],
        status: json["status"],
        statusClass: json["status_class"],
        purchaseDate: DateTime.parse(json["purchase_date"]),
        warrantyPeriod: json["warranty_period"],
        warrantyExpires: DateTime.parse(json["warranty_expires"]),
        warrantyStatus: json["warranty_status"],
        temperatureClass: json["temperature_class"],
        temperatureMetric: json["temperature_metric"],
        temperatureImperial: json["temperature_imperial"],
        surgeProtection: json["surge_protection"],
        totalProducts: json["total_products"],
        temperatureLowThreshold: json["temperature_low_threshold"],
        temperatureHighThreshold: json["temperature_high_threshold"],
        notes: json["notes"],
        importId: json["import_id"],
        deleted: json["deleted"],
        createdBy: json["created_by"],
        lastUpdatedBy: json["last_updated_by"],
        deletedBy: json["deleted_by"],
        dateCreated: json["date_created"],
        dateModified: json["date_modified"],
        dateDeleted: json["date_deleted"],
        scope: json["scope"],
        owner: json["owner"],
        links: DeviceLinks.fromJson(json["links"]),
        ports: List<Port>.from(json["ports"].map((x) => Port.fromJson(x))),
        iotDeviceTags: List<IotDeviceTag>.from(json["iot_device_tags"].map((x) => IotDeviceTag.fromJson(x))),
        entityAddresses: List<EntityAddress>.from(json["entity_addresses"].map((x) => EntityAddress.fromJson(x))),
        availablePorts: List<String>.from(json["available_ports"].map((x) => x)),
        mobile: Mobile.fromJson(json["mobile"]),
    );
}

class EntityAddress {
    EntityAddress({
        required this.entityAddressesId,
        required this.objectRef,
        required this.objectId,
        required this.address1,
        required this.address2,
        required this.city,
        required this.state,
        required this.zipCode,
        required this.zipCodeExt,
        required this.countryName,
        required this.countryIso2,
        required this.countryIso3,
        required this.countryId,
        required this.fullSingleLineAddress,
        required this.fullMultiLineAddress,
        required this.addressType,
        required this.prime,
        required this.primeType,
        required this.primeClass,
        required this.mapsLink,
        required this.deleted,
        required this.createdBy,
        required this.lastUpdatedBy,
        required this.deletedBy,
        required this.dateCreated,
        required this.dateModified,
        required this.dateDeleted,
        required this.links,
    });

    String entityAddressesId;
    String objectRef;
    String objectId;
    String address1;
    String address2;
    String city;
    String state;
    String zipCode;
    dynamic zipCodeExt;
    String countryName;
    String countryIso2;
    String countryIso3;
    String countryId;
    String fullSingleLineAddress;
    String fullMultiLineAddress;
    String addressType;
    String prime;
    String primeType;
    String primeClass;
    String mapsLink;
    String deleted;
    String createdBy;
    String lastUpdatedBy;
    dynamic deletedBy;
    String dateCreated;
    String dateModified;
    dynamic dateDeleted;
    EntityAddressLinks links;

    factory EntityAddress.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => EntityAddress(
        entityAddressesId: json["entity_addresses_id"],
        objectRef: json["object_ref"],
        objectId: json["object_id"],
        address1: json["address1"],
        address2: json["address2"],
        city: json["city"],
        state: json["state"],
        zipCode: json["zip_code"],
        zipCodeExt: json["zip_code_ext"],
        countryName: json["country_name"],
        countryIso2: json["country_iso_2"],
        countryIso3: json["country_iso_3"],
        countryId: json["country_id"],
        fullSingleLineAddress: json["full_single_line_address"],
        fullMultiLineAddress: json["full_multi_line_address"],
        addressType: json["address_type"],
        prime: json["prime"],
        primeType: json["prime_type"],
        primeClass: json["prime_class"],
        mapsLink: json["maps_link"],
        deleted: json["deleted"],
        createdBy: json["created_by"],
        lastUpdatedBy: json["last_updated_by"],
        deletedBy: json["deleted_by"],
        dateCreated: json["date_created"],
        dateModified: json["date_modified"],
        dateDeleted: json["date_deleted"],
        links: EntityAddressLinks.fromJson(json["links"]),
    );
}

class EntityAddressLinks {
    EntityAddressLinks({
        required this.self,
    });

    String self;

    factory EntityAddressLinks.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => EntityAddressLinks(
        self: json["self"],
    );
}

class IotDeviceTag {
    IotDeviceTag({
        required this.id,
        required this.deviceId,
        required this.tagId,
        required this.tag,
        required this.companyId,
        required this.createdBy,
        required this.lastUpdatedBy,
        required this.deletedBy,
        required this.dateCreated,
        required this.dateModified,
        required this.dateDeleted,
        required this.scope,
        required this.owner,
        required this.links,
    });

    String id;
    String deviceId;
    String tagId;
    String tag;
    String companyId;
    String createdBy;
    dynamic lastUpdatedBy;
    dynamic deletedBy;
    String dateCreated;
    dynamic dateModified;
    dynamic dateDeleted;
    String scope;
    String owner;
    EntityAddressLinks links;

    factory IotDeviceTag.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => IotDeviceTag(
        id: json["id"],
        deviceId: json["device_id"],
        tagId: json["tag_id"],
        tag: json["tag"],
        companyId: json["company_id"],
        createdBy: json["created_by"],
        lastUpdatedBy: json["last_updated_by"],
        deletedBy: json["deleted_by"],
        dateCreated: json["date_created"],
        dateModified: json["date_modified"],
        dateDeleted: json["date_deleted"],
        scope: json["scope"],
        owner: json["owner"],
        links: EntityAddressLinks.fromJson(json["links"]),
    );
}

class DeviceLinks {
    DeviceLinks({
        required this.self,
        required this.customer,
    });

    String self;
    String customer;

    factory DeviceLinks.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => DeviceLinks(
        self: json["self"],
        customer: json["customer"],
    );
}

class Mobile {
    Mobile({
        required this.deviceName,
        required this.sim,
        required this.imei,
        required this.hologramDeviceId,
        required this.whenCreated,
        required this.simState,
        required this.overageLimit,
        required this.currentBillingData,
        required this.lastNetworkUsed,
        required this.lastConnected,
        this.lastSessionBytes,
        this.lastSessionBegin,
        this.lastSessionEnd,
        this.networkName,
        this.radioTech,
        this.simActive,
        this.linkId,
    });

    String deviceName;
    String sim;
    String imei;
    int hologramDeviceId;
    DateTime whenCreated;
    String simState;
    int overageLimit;
    int currentBillingData;
    String lastNetworkUsed;
    String lastConnected;
    dynamic lastSessionBytes;
    dynamic lastSessionBegin;
    dynamic lastSessionEnd;
    dynamic networkName;
    dynamic radioTech;
    dynamic simActive;
    dynamic linkId;

    factory Mobile.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Mobile(
        deviceName: json["device_name"],
        sim: json["sim"],
        imei: json["imei"],
        hologramDeviceId: json["hologram_device_id"],
        whenCreated: DateTime.parse(json["when_created"]),
        simState: json["sim_state"],
        overageLimit: json["overage_limit"],
        currentBillingData: json["current_billing_data"],
        lastNetworkUsed: json["last_network_used"],
        lastConnected: json["last_connected"],
        lastSessionBytes: json["last_session_bytes"],
        lastSessionBegin: json["last_session_begin"],
        lastSessionEnd: json["last_session_end"],
        networkName: json["network_name"],
        radioTech: json["radio_tech"],
        simActive: json["sim_active"],
        linkId: json["link_id"],
    );
}

class Port {
    Port({
        required this.devicePortsId,
        required this.deviceId,
        required this.companyId,
        required this.company,
        required this.productId,
        required this.productName,
        required this.portNumber,
        required this.version,
        required this.sensorTypeId,
        required this.sensorType,
        required this.sensorDescription,
        required this.imperialSymbol,
        required this.metricSymbol,
        required this.fillVolumeGallons,
        required this.fillVolumeLiters,
        required this.totalGallonsCapacity,
        required this.totalLitersCapacity,
        required this.percentFull,
        required this.tankTypeId,
        required this.tankType,
        required this.slug,
        required this.imageUrl,
        required this.formula,
        required this.reorderYellow,
        required this.reorderRed,
        required this.deleted,
        required this.createdBy,
        required this.lastUpdatedBy,
        required this.deletedBy,
        required this.dateCreated,
        required this.dateModified,
        required this.dateDeleted,
        required this.scope,
        required this.owner,
        required this.links,
        required this.tankSpecs,
    });

    String devicePortsId;
    String deviceId;
    String companyId;
    String company;
    String productId;
    String productName;
    String portNumber;
    String version;
    String sensorTypeId;
    String sensorType;
    String sensorDescription;
    String imperialSymbol;
    String metricSymbol;
    String fillVolumeGallons;
    String fillVolumeLiters;
    String totalGallonsCapacity;
    String totalLitersCapacity;
    String percentFull;
    String tankTypeId;
    TankType? tankType;
    Slug? slug;
    String imageUrl;
    String formula;
    String reorderYellow;
    String reorderRed;
    String deleted;
    dynamic createdBy;
    String lastUpdatedBy;
    dynamic deletedBy;
    String dateCreated;
    String dateModified;
    dynamic dateDeleted;
    String scope;
    String owner;
    EntityAddressLinks links;
    List<TankSpec> tankSpecs;

    factory Port.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Port(
        devicePortsId: json["device_ports_id"],
        deviceId: json["device_id"],
        companyId: json["company_id"],
        company: json["company"],
        productId: json["product_id"],
        productName: json["product_name"],
        portNumber: json["port_number"],
        version: json["version"],
        sensorTypeId: json["sensor_type_id"],
        sensorType: json["sensor_type"],
        sensorDescription: json["sensor_description"],
        imperialSymbol: json["imperial_symbol"],
        metricSymbol: json["metric_symbol"],
        fillVolumeGallons: json["fill_volume_gallons"],
        fillVolumeLiters: json["fill_volume_liters"],
        totalGallonsCapacity: json["total_gallons_capacity"],
        totalLitersCapacity: json["total_liters_capacity"],
        percentFull: json["percent_full"],
        tankTypeId: json["tank_type_id"],
        tankType: tankTypeValues.map[json["tank_type"]],
        slug: slugValues.map[json["slug"]],
        imageUrl: json["image_url"],
        formula: json["formula"],
        reorderYellow: json["reorder_yellow"],
        reorderRed: json["reorder_red"],
        deleted: json["deleted"],
        createdBy: json["created_by"],
        lastUpdatedBy: json["last_updated_by"],
        deletedBy: json["deleted_by"],
        dateCreated: json["date_created"],
        dateModified: json["date_modified"],
        dateDeleted: json["date_deleted"],
        scope: json["scope"],
        owner: json["owner"],
        links: EntityAddressLinks.fromJson(json["links"]),
        tankSpecs: List<TankSpec>.from(json["tank_specs"].map((x) => TankSpec.fromJson(x))),
    );
}

enum Slug { VERTICAL_CYLINDER, VERTICAL_OVAL, RECTANGULAR }

final slugValues = EnumValues({
    "rectangular": Slug.RECTANGULAR,
    "vertical_cylinder": Slug.VERTICAL_CYLINDER,
    "vertical_oval": Slug.VERTICAL_OVAL
});

class TankSpec {
    TankSpec({
        required this.id,
        required this.devicePortsId,
        required this.tankTypeId,
        required this.tankType,
        required this.slug,
        required this.defUsGallons,
        required this.defLiters,
        required this.metricDiameter,
        required this.metricHeight,
        required this.metricWidth,
        required this.metricLength,
        required this.sensorOffset,
        required this.imperialDiameter,
        required this.imperialHeight,
        required this.imperialWidth,
        required this.imperialLength,
        required this.usGallons,
        required this.liters,
        required this.gallonCalcDiff,
        required this.dimensionDisplay,
        required this.template,
        required this.createdBy,
        required this.lastUpdatedBy,
        required this.deletedBy,
        required this.dateCreated,
        required this.dateModified,
        required this.dateDeleted,
        required this.links,
    });

    String id;
    String devicePortsId;
    String tankTypeId;
    TankType? tankType;
    Slug? slug;
    String defUsGallons;
    String defLiters;
    String metricDiameter;
    String metricHeight;
    String metricWidth;
    String metricLength;
    String sensorOffset;
    String imperialDiameter;
    String imperialHeight;
    String imperialWidth;
    String imperialLength;
    String usGallons;
    String liters;
    String gallonCalcDiff;
    String dimensionDisplay;
    String template;
    String createdBy;
    String lastUpdatedBy;
    dynamic deletedBy;
    String dateCreated;
    String dateModified;
    dynamic dateDeleted;
    EntityAddressLinks links;

    factory TankSpec.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => TankSpec(
        id: json["id"],
        devicePortsId: json["device_ports_id"],
        tankTypeId: json["tank_type_id"],
        tankType: tankTypeValues.map[json["tank_type"]],
        slug: slugValues.map[json["slug"]],
        defUsGallons: json["def_us_gallons"],
        defLiters: json["def_liters"],
        metricDiameter: json["metric_diameter"],
        metricHeight: json["metric_height"] == null ? null : json["metric_height"],
        metricWidth: json["metric_width"] == null ? null : json["metric_width"],
        metricLength: json["metric_length"],
        sensorOffset: json["sensor_offset"],
        imperialDiameter: json["imperial_diameter"],
        imperialHeight: json["imperial_height"] == null ? null : json["imperial_height"],
        imperialWidth: json["imperial_width"] == null ? null : json["imperial_width"],
        imperialLength: json["imperial_length"],
        usGallons: json["us_gallons"] == null ? null : json["us_gallons"],
        liters: json["liters"] == null ? null : json["liters"],
        gallonCalcDiff: json["gallon_calc_diff"],
        dimensionDisplay: json["dimension_display"] == null ? null : json["dimension_display"],
        template: json["template"],
        createdBy: json["created_by"],
        lastUpdatedBy: json["last_updated_by"] == null ? null : json["last_updated_by"],
        deletedBy: json["deleted_by"],
        dateCreated: json["date_created"],
        dateModified: json["date_modified"] == null ? null : json["date_modified"],
        dateDeleted: json["date_deleted"],
        links: EntityAddressLinks.fromJson(json["links"]),
    );
}

enum TankType { VERTICAL_CYLINDER, VERTICAL_OVAL, RECTANGULAR_SHAPE }

final tankTypeValues = EnumValues({
    "Rectangular Shape": TankType.RECTANGULAR_SHAPE,
    "Vertical Cylinder": TankType.VERTICAL_CYLINDER,
    "Vertical Oval": TankType.VERTICAL_OVAL
});

class EnumValues<T> {
    Map<String, T> map;
    late Map<T, String> reverseMap;

    EnumValues(this.map);

    Map<T, String> get reverse {
        if (reverseMap == null) {
            reverseMap = map.map((k, v) => new MapEntry(v, k));
        }
        return reverseMap;
    }
}
```

Here is the code in my api_services file where i am referring to my data model file.

```
    class ApiService {
  Future getSingleDevice(int id) async {
    // print(AppConstants.API_KEY);
    // print(AppConstants.TOKEN);
    final singleDeviceUrl = Uri.parse(AppConstants.BASE_URL +
        AppConstants.DEVICE_LIST_URI +
        '/' +
        id.toString());
    print(singleDeviceUrl);
    final response = await http.get(singleDeviceUrl, headers: {
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + AppConstants.TOKEN,
      'X-API-KEY': AppConstants.API_KEY
    });
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      print(response.body);
      print(json);
      // var body = json.decode(response.body);
      // return DeviceClass.fromJson(body);
    } else {
      print(response.statusCode);
      print(response.body);
      print("no data");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you do: `print(json)` to check what are inside the parsed `json` object?

Comment: it just says 'Instance of JsonCodec'

Comment: You should print it somewhere where you actually have access to the `json` variable you are using in the screenshots. But you can also try call it something else since `json` are already something declared inside `dart:convert`.

Comment: I also did a print(json.decode(response.body)) and it gives me the full response with the value of the questionable key filled, which is what I would expect I guess.  I am just perplexed as to why it would be considered null.

Comment: Well, we need more context to know for sure what is going on. You have basically not shown us any relevant code. E.g. where is `json` being defined and how? Post the full method if you can.

Comment: Im not sure where I would do that as I am new to Dart. The screenshots above are in reference to my model file. I don't believe I can put a print statement there.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246782/discussion-between-julemand101-and-mackina).